# Escape semicolon in bash

Tags: bash, command, line

I need to write script that prints all command line parameters. So i just simply put
`echo "$@"`. However, when you launch script like that:

```
./script.sh first argument ;;; second argument.;
```

Is there any way to escape those semicolons?

Comment: Just quote them `./script.sh 'first argument' ';;;' 'second argument.;'`

Comment: @anubhava Yep, that one will work, is there any way to do it without quoting?

Comment: @Evgeny No, there is no way. An unquoted `;` has a special meaning; it is used to separate commands by shell. Since this is done by shell, the command cannot see it as an argument (when unquoted).

Comment: @Evgeny: If you are working in shell get used to quoting

Comment: @M.NejatAydin thank you for answer, seems like our lecturer just giving us impossible tasks to troll.

Comment: @anubhava I don't have problem with quoting, it is homework that impossible to accomplish I guess.

Comment: @Evgeny But there are different methods to quote. For instance, you could quote (or escape) them (the spaces and semicolons) like that: `./script.sh first\ argument \;\;\; second\ argument.\;`